# How to fetch from all remote repositories by default

Tags: git, git-fetch

As far as I can tell, `git fetch` doesn't have much in the way of side-effects.

Is it possible to configure git to fetch from all remote repositories by default when running `git fetch`, rather than having to pass in the `--all` option?

Answer (score 4):

While you have to provide a group name or `--multiple` or `--all` to `git fetch` to make it fetch from multiple remotes, the `git remote update` command defaults to updating the remotes defined by `remotes.default` if that is set, or else all remotes except those for which `remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate` is set to `true`.

In other words, by default, `git remote update` means "fetch from all".